# Do I have to digitaly sign my Excel Add-In?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, certificate

I've an Add-In which will be deployed on all PCs in a company. We are going to put it into the `c:\Users\Ernst\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` folder.

I tested this localy on my machine and everything works as expected.

Is there a reason I should digitally sign the Add-In with a certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signing will prevent any confirmation prompts to the user of "Do you want to load this add-in", otherwise you'll be fine.  As long as they click Yes to any of the prompts and have the appropriate security level set to load them, that is.